# Material Render View different from Material/Texture View

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

First basic model from an illustration. In the material or texture View Port Shading, it looks just like I want it to, but when I go to "Render" (Render Image), this nastiness happens. The uv mapping from the back building decides to just repeat itself and not adhere to the uv mapping at all. I created a texture (painted outside of Blender following  UV mapping layout) and then imported the image, and also created and assigned the image to the material.

What could I be doing so wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hi there, perhaps you could share your file in some way and I/we could take a look at it.

Comment: No problem, I will upload to dropbox tonight and edit the question!

Comment: Here´s the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/amb4jajudwxlb6f/gringotts.fbx?dl=0